# Limit in pandas "replace" seems to not work

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I found an unexpected behavior of `limit` argument while using `pandas.DataFrame.replace` on a vector.

While executing the following:

```
import pandas as pd
array = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,3,2,3,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,3])

array_replace = array.replace(3, 5)
array_limit = array.replace(3, 5, limit=3)
```

I expect `array_replace` and `array_limit` to be different. However

```
print(array_replace.to_numpy().reshape(-1))
print(array_limit.to_numpy().reshape(-1))
print(f'Arrays are equal: {array_replace.equals(array_limit)}')
```

gives (whatever `method` used)

```
[1 2 5 5 2 5 1 2 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 1 1 1 2 5]
[1 2 5 5 2 5 1 2 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 1 1 1 2 5]
Arrays are equal: True
```

The same is **not** true when using NaNs and `pandas.DataFrame.fillna` instead:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
array = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,3,2,3,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,3])
array[array==3] = np.nan

array_replace = array.fillna(5)
array_limit = array.fillna(5, limit=3)

print(array_replace.to_numpy().reshape(-1))
print(array_limit.to_numpy().reshape(-1))
print(f'Arrays are equal: {array_replace.equals(array_limit)}')

# Out:
# [1. 2. 5. 5. 2. 5. 1. 2. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 5. 1. 1. 1. 2. 5.]
# [ 1.  2.  5.  5.  2.  5.  1.  2. nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan  1.
#   1.  1.  2. nan]
# Arrays are equal: False
```

Why is `limit` working differently in the two cases?

Tested on Python 3.8.3, Pandas 1.2.4

Comment: What is your expectation of how array_limit should look like? Maybe this is just an issue of wrong expectation of how the limit parameter is working.

Comment: I expect it to look similar to NaNs case, with 3s instead of NaNs. Even if it is not the case, I expect some differences in the two outcoming arrays, but I could not make `limit` affect the resulting vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `limit` parameter works only in relation with the `method` paramter. But the method parameter only works with `value = None`.

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

> **method** {‘pad’, ‘ffill’, ‘bfill’, None}: The method to use when for replacement, when to_replace is a scalar, list or tuple and value is None.

and

> **limit** int, default None:    Maximum size gap to forward or backward fill.

A working example of the usage of the limit parameter:

```py
import pandas as pd
array = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,3,2,3,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,3])
array_replace = array.replace(3, None, method='ffill')
array_limit = array.replace(3, None, limit=3, method='ffill')
```

Output:

```
array_replace = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
array_limit =   [1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood the use of `limit`. Still, I don't get why two functions as similar as `replace` and `fillna` should behave in such different ways wrt `value`. That's another problem though. Thank you